# Moodle Baracuda check bypass or highest antelope version

Tags: mysql, moodle

On our server, we cannot change any database settings and newer versions of Moodle require the barracuda file format as opposed to antelope.

We are running 3.4.1. 3.5+ requires innoDB. I thought a point upgrade to 3.4.4 would be ok, but that also has the same problems.

What is the highest version I could use? Or is it possible to bypass these checks and continue using current database?

```
Your database uses Antelope as the file format. Full UTF-8 support in MySQL and MariaDB requires the Barracuda file format. Please switch to the Barracuda file format. See the documentation MySQL full unicode support for details.

Check
mysql_full_unicode_support#Large_prefix 
this test must pass
For full support of UTF-8 both MySQL and MariaDB require you to change your MySQL setting 'innodb_large_prefix' to 'ON'. See the documentation for further details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix this by editing my config.php with

```
dbcollation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

In other words, partial mySQL as opposed to full made baracudda support optional.